# javascript scroll event inconsistency

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, scroll

I was trying to trigger a scroll event.
And found out that this simple task is not so simple.

Using jQuery v1.9.1
**Code**

```
var win = $(window);
win.on("scroll", function(){
    console.log("running");
});
// trigger the scroll event
win.trigger("scroll"); //no success 

// change the scrollTop to +1
win.scrollTop(win.scrollTop()+1) //no success 

// change the scrollTop to -1
win.scrollTop(win.scrollTop()-1) //no success

// change the scrollTop to +2
win.scrollTop(win.scrollTop()+2) //fires twice

// change the scrollTop to +1.7
win.scrollTop(win.scrollTop()+1.7) //fires twice
```

Is there a correct reliable way to trigger a scroll event?
 See jsFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/u9dygoxf/1/

Comment: `win.trigger("scroll");` writes the log line for me...

Comment: The correct way to trigger the event handler would be `.trigger("scroll")`, not changing a property.

Comment: All of your examples work for me -- I'm running them from the console on this page. Is there a chance you forgot to load jQuery in your page?

Comment: No, It turns out that my test wasn't fully isolated.. Sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the `scroll` event is actually only triggered if you *manually* trigger it or the `scrollTop()` function actually scrolls the window.

This will always alert a value, although sometimes it's zero:

```
var win = $(window);
win.on('scroll', function() {
  alert('scrolled: ' + win.scrollTop());
});
win.trigger('scroll');
```

This will alert a value as long as the page is not already scrolled all the way to the bottom.

```
var win = $(window);
win.on('scroll', function() {
  alert('scrolled: ' + win.scrollTop());
});
win.scrollTop(win.scrollTop() + 1);
```

This will alert a value as long as the page is not already scrolled all the way to the top.

```
var win = $(window);
win.on('scroll', function() {
  alert('scrolled: ' + win.scrollTop());
});
win.scrollTop(win.scrollTop() - 1);
```